# Saving state locally as well as offsite

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I need to save user information so its updated locally and offsite. So if theres no internet connection it will still continue to work and be persistent after a restart etc. and when the internet comes back up it syncs that info offsite.

So is it best to use The Local Datastore within Parse or just use a combination of SQLite and ParseObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

Your on the right track. No need for third party libraries. Parse's local datastore does exactly what your goal's intent is. Further more parse also has great caching policies to utilize.

Explicitly, Local Datastore uses Apples libs.sqlite3.0 framework but does all the work for you. So it's down to your personal preference, do you want to learn sqlite (which isn't a bad thing and do it yourself) or have parse local datastore do it all for you? It's essentially an alternative to that and Core Data, my guess an incentive for you to use parse if your a beginning developer as opposed to learning the alternatives

Pros to using Local Datastore :

- You are already familiar with Parse framework and code syntax, easy transition
- Easy handling for network woes
- Updating/querying and referencing is simpler than sqlite syntax

Cons :

- Local datastore still utilizes API request for queries and pins, so there is no getting around that
- saveEventually if it doesn't work the first go, it will retry again but without a success block
- some bugs have come up (this could be circumstantial, but just no other users are having difficulties with implementing)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what would best practice be? Try and store the object as normal in parse and then if no internet, store in the Local Datastore?

Comment: You could do it either way @Dan, your way or look at it the other way, you could store it in Local Datastore if you know internet reachability is nil, and then update to the backend when service is available again. Or if you don't know or care to code for reachability, you could use saveEventually which takes care of this for you, it tries to save the object to the backend, but if it fails due to internet complications or otherwise, it will try again once the app is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I combine AFNetworking and Parse.  This is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial.

Basically, whenever you need information, you query the local database rather than the remote database.  However, you use the SyncEngine to make sure that the local database and remote database are always in sync.